# Windows 2003 as L2TP server (without IPsec) L2TP PPP

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, l2tp

Is there a way to configure Windows server (2003/2008) as a traditional L2TP server without having IPsec . I have an L2TP client which is similar to an LAC and dials in to the LNS using SCCRQ and gets IP using DHCP on the client.

I configured the RAS and parameters but cannot get it work. Any advice? I was able to do IPsec but my client doesnt support IPsec, just traditional plain L2TP.

Answer (score 0):

Windows automatically creates an IPSec policy for L2TP connections because L2TP doesn't encrypt data. However, in your situation that you need L2TP connection without the security of IPSec, you must disable IPSec on both the client and server:

**On server side:**

Open Services -- Click on Start > Programs > Administrative Tools > Services then disable IPSec service

**In order to disable IPSec on Windows 7/Vista**

1) Click Start, then in search box type: run ENTER

2) In the Run dialog type: regedit ENTER

3) In Registry Editor: Locate and then click the following registry subkey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Rasman\Parameters

4) On the Edit menu, click New>DWORD

5) As the name of the new key enter: ProhibitIpSec

6) Double click the key to edit the value.

7) In the Value data field, enter: 1

8) Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

Hope it could help